# view controller changed after cocoapods installation

Tags: xcode, storyboard, cocoapods, viewcontroller

I was trying to test alamofire in my Xcode project but after pod installation and cocoa-pods installation and setup instead of view controller i see root view controller and Dataviewcontroller. How can i change back it  to only view controller. I adding a snapshot of  a project before the cocoapods installation and after the installation. before the installation there was only showing view controller but now it shows root view controller and DataViewController in every new project

My Xcode version is 7.3.1

please help me out.... 
[image]

Comment: tap left from the emulator (where it says 'alamofirproject' and see if you can't select 'MyUniversityHood'). It's not possible that the installation of cocoa-pods would change your files like this

Comment: @SoundShock i think you have miss understood both are different project I was showing a project before the cocoapods installation and after the installation. before the installation there was only showing view controller but now it shows root view controller and DataViewController in every new project... sorry for not well description I am changing that now.. and If you can PLEASE HELP ME.... :(

Comment: what pod exactly are you installing?

Comment: @SoundShock alamofire i was trying to install...

Comment: just to be sure, check this tutorial on how to install cocoapods etc. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6iJI3mBeRM 
If you did the same things that have been done here, I can't help you anymore. I use alamofire in my own projects (installed with pods) and never has it changed files.